# Optimal population allocation layout over the Earth

Tags: optimization, resource-economics, population-economics

Does exist some model of optimal people occupancy over whole our planet?

Something accounting for climate, resources (with and without existing settlements) availability, progress and grows perspectives and so on.
I would like to find it in form of heat map.
All I can find is just studies about cities layout or population size and density.

I came to the question thinking about advisability of my little hometown existence and ways to improve it - may be the game is not worth the candle.

Comment: This seems to be more of an economic geography question than an economics question. That said, it has been argued elsewhere on this forum that economic geography is a sub-field of economics. I would in that case suggest we add a tag “economic geography”.
https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/39283/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-disciplines-of-economics-and-economic-geogr

Answer (score -1):

The closest I can find to what I believe you’re looking for would be the [biocapacity map](https://data.footprintnetwork.org/#/) of the Global Footprint Network. They don't seem to publish granular spatial data, i.e. where in a country its biocapacity is located.

Note, however, that actual economic activity does not correspond to local biocapacity because high density stock energy (fossil fuel) can be transported to population centres. ([Source](https://portal.research.lu.se/portal/en/publications/fossil-capital(87f140d1-97fc-4d6c-9e6b-8749c286877b).html))